# parse json with php double array that leads to the following array's data

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am having an issue with trying to find the right thing to do here because the first two arrays affect the data in the remaining arrays in the json file.

To see the actual JSON file the link is here: http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=36.3219&lon=-96.8058&FcstType=digitalJSON

Looking at the Arrays, the "PeriodNumberList" has a list of days in it that corresponds to a number, then that number carries to the array underneath it to spit out the name of the day within the "PeriodNameList" array.

This is where it gets tricky. Now the NAMES of the arrays from here on, are generated from the two arrays above which is where I am having my issue parsing with dynamic JSON file. Remember that the names of the arrays below these two are constantly changing which is the reasoning to why I tried parsing it the way I did.

Here is my code for my attempt to try and carry the information from the two arrays mentioned over to generate the following arrays and be able to parse them but to no avail.

```
<?php

    $url = "http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?    lat=36.3219&lon=-96.8058&FcstType=digitalJSON";

// create curl resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

//return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch); 

$json_a = json_decode($output,true);



// <---------- Period List -------------> //

    $period0 = $json_a['PeriodNameList']['0'];

// <---------- Hourly Next 12 ----------> //

    $hourly_next_12_period = $json_a['$period0']['periodName'];

    $hourly_next_12_time_0 = $json_a['$period0']['time'][0];
    $hourly_next_12_time_1 = $json_a['$period0']['time'][1];
    $hourly_next_12_time_2 = $json_a['$period0']['time'][2];
    $hourly_next_12_time_3 = $json_a['$period0']['time'][3];
    $hourly_next_12_time_4 = $json_a['$period0']['time'][4];
    $hourly_next_12_time_5 = $json_a['$period0']['time'][5];
    $hourly_next_12_time_6 = $json_a['$period0']['time'][6];
    $hourly_next_12_time_7 = $json_a['$period0']['time'][7];
    $hourly_next_12_time_8 = $json_a['$period0']['time'][8];
    $hourly_next_12_time_9 = $json_a['$period0']['time'][9];
    $hourly_next_12_time_10 = $json_a['$period0']['time'][10];
    $hourly_next_12_time_11 = $json_a['$period0']['time'][11];
  ?>
```

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: please note the $url at the top I added for spaces within the url by accident while making this post, please disregard that and remove the space when trying out the code.

Comment: I have done some research into JSON Arrays, multidimensional arrays, and different ways to parse it in PHP to no avail.

Comment: I have visited w3schools, stackoverflow, php.net and more without being able to find examples of this type of array.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out after searching the internet high and low... I took some time away then came back with a fresh perspective and figured it out on my own.

Its going to sound weird but I am quite new at this and am quite surprised that I was able to figure this out on my own.

I had to take the "PeriodNameList" and parse that, then now to parse the arrays I wanted to parse below those, I basically had to "pre-parse" the "PeriodNameList" in a separate PHP file, then INCLUDE that result into the next PHP parse page so it would include the results in the new parsing algorithm.

It looks like this...

First Parse PHP Page (The Pre-Parse)

```
<?php

$url = "http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=36.3219&lon=-96.8058&FcstType=digitalJSON";

// create curl resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

//return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch); 

$json_a = json_decode($output,true);



// <---------- Period List -------------> //

    $period0 = $json_a['PeriodNameList']['0'];
    $period1 = $json_a['PeriodNameList']['1'];
    $period2 = $json_a['PeriodNameList']['2'];
    $period3 = $json_a['PeriodNameList']['3'];
    $period4 = $json_a['PeriodNameList']['4'];
    $period5 = $json_a['PeriodNameList']['5'];
    $period6 = $json_a['PeriodNameList']['6'];
    $period7 = $json_a['PeriodNameList']['7'];
    $period8 = $json_a['PeriodNameList']['8'];
    $period9 = $json_a['PeriodNameList']['9'];
    $period10 = $json_a['PeriodNameList']['10'];
    $period11 = $json_a['PeriodNameList']['11'];
    $period12 = $json_a['PeriodNameList']['12'];
    $period13 = $json_a['PeriodNameList']['13'];



    ?>
```

Then now I have to include the results for the next Parsing phase in the second parse....

```
<?php

require 'req/weatherinfo_hourly_period.php';

?>

<?php

$url = "http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=36.3219&lon=-96.8058&FcstType=digitalJSON";

// create curl resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

//return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch); 

$json_a = json_decode($output,true);




// <---------- Hourly Next 12 ----------> //

    $hourly_next_12_period = $json_a[$period0]['periodName'];

    $hourly_next_12_time_0 = $json_a[$period0]['time'][0];
    $hourly_next_12_time_1 = $json_a[$period0]['time'][1];
    $hourly_next_12_time_2 = $json_a[$period0]['time'][2];
    $hourly_next_12_time_3 = $json_a[$period0]['time'][3];
    $hourly_next_12_time_4 = $json_a[$period0]['time'][4];
    $hourly_next_12_time_5 = $json_a[$period0]['time'][5];
    $hourly_next_12_time_6 = $json_a[$period0]['time'][6];
    $hourly_next_12_time_7 = $json_a[$period0]['time'][7];
    $hourly_next_12_time_8 = $json_a[$period0]['time'][8];
    $hourly_next_12_time_9 = $json_a[$period0]['time'][9];
    $hourly_next_12_time_10 = $json_a[$period0]['time'][10];
    $hourly_next_12_time_11 = $json_a[$period0]['time'][11];

    $hourly_next_12_windchill_0 = $json_a[$period0]['windChill'][0];
    $hourly_next_12_windchill_1 = $json_a[$period0]['windChill'][1];
    $hourly_next_12_windchill_2 = $json_a[$period0]['windChill'][2];
    $hourly_next_12_windchill_3 = $json_a[$period0]['windChill'][3];
    $hourly_next_12_windchill_4 = $json_a[$period0]['windChill'][4];
    $hourly_next_12_windchill_5 = $json_a[$period0]['windChill'][5];
    $hourly_next_12_windchill_6 = $json_a[$period0]['windChill'][6];
    $hourly_next_12_windchill_7 = $json_a[$period0]['windChill'][7];
    $hourly_next_12_windchill_8 = $json_a[$period0]['windChill'][8];
    $hourly_next_12_windchill_9 = $json_a[$period0]['windChill'][9];
    $hourly_next_12_windchill_10 = $json_a[$period0]['windChill'][10];
    $hourly_next_12_windchill_11 = $json_a[$period0]['windChill'][11];

    $hourly_next_12_windspeed_0 = $json_a[$period0]['windSpeed'][0];
    $hourly_next_12_windspeed_1 = $json_a[$period0]['windSpeed'][1];
    $hourly_next_12_windspeed_2 = $json_a[$period0]['windSpeed'][2];
    $hourly_next_12_windspeed_3 = $json_a[$period0]['windSpeed'][3];
    $hourly_next_12_windspeed_4 = $json_a[$period0]['windSpeed'][4];
    $hourly_next_12_windspeed_5 = $json_a[$period0]['windSpeed'][5];
    $hourly_next_12_windspeed_6 = $json_a[$period0]['windSpeed'][6];
    $hourly_next_12_windspeed_7 = $json_a[$period0]['windSpeed'][7];
    $hourly_next_12_windspeed_8 = $json_a[$period0]['windSpeed'][8];
    $hourly_next_12_windspeed_9 = $json_a[$period0]['windSpeed'][9];
    $hourly_next_12_windspeed_10 = $json_a[$period0]['windSpeed'][10];
    $hourly_next_12_windspeed_11 = $json_a[$period0]['windSpeed'][11];

    $hourly_next_12_winddirectioncardinal_0 = $json_a[$period0]['windDirectionCardinal'][0];
    $hourly_next_12_winddirectioncardinal_1 = $json_a[$period0]['windDirectionCardinal'][1];
    $hourly_next_12_winddirectioncardinal_2 = $json_a[$period0]['windDirectionCardinal'][2];
    $hourly_next_12_winddirectioncardinal_3 = $json_a[$period0]['windDirectionCardinal'][3];
    $hourly_next_12_winddirectioncardinal_4 = $json_a[$period0]['windDirectionCardinal'][4];
    $hourly_next_12_winddirectioncardinal_5 = $json_a[$period0]['windDirectionCardinal'][5];
    $hourly_next_12_winddirectioncardinal_6 = $json_a[$period0]['windDirectionCardinal'][6];
    $hourly_next_12_winddirectioncardinal_7 = $json_a[$period0]['windDirectionCardinal'][7];
    $hourly_next_12_winddirectioncardinal_8 = $json_a[$period0]['windDirectionCardinal'][8];
    $hourly_next_12_winddirectioncardinal_9 = $json_a[$period0]['windDirectionCardinal'][9];
    $hourly_next_12_winddirectioncardinal_10 = $json_a[$period0]['windDirectionCardinal'][10];
    $hourly_next_12_winddirectioncardinal_11 = $json_a[$period0]['windDirectionCardinal'][11];

    $hourly_next_12_windGust_0 = $json_a[$period0]['windGust'][0];
    $hourly_next_12_windGust_1 = $json_a[$period0]['windGust'][1];
    $hourly_next_12_windGust_2 = $json_a[$period0]['windGust'][2];
    $hourly_next_12_windGust_3 = $json_a[$period0]['windGust'][3];
    $hourly_next_12_windGust_4 = $json_a[$period0]['windGust'][4];
    $hourly_next_12_windGust_5 = $json_a[$period0]['windGust'][5];
    $hourly_next_12_windGust_6 = $json_a[$period0]['windGust'][6];
    $hourly_next_12_windGust_7 = $json_a[$period0]['windGust'][7];
    $hourly_next_12_windGust_8 = $json_a[$period0]['windGust'][8];
    $hourly_next_12_windGust_9 = $json_a[$period0]['windGust'][9];
    $hourly_next_12_windGust_10 = $json_a[$period0]['windGust'][10];
    $hourly_next_12_windGust_11 = $json_a[$period0]['windGust'][12];

    $hourly_next_12_iconLink_0 = $json_a[$period0]['iconLink'][0];
    $hourly_next_12_iconLink_1 = $json_a[$period0]['iconLink'][1];
    $hourly_next_12_iconLink_2 = $json_a[$period0]['iconLink'][2];
    $hourly_next_12_iconLink_3 = $json_a[$period0]['iconLink'][3];
    $hourly_next_12_iconLink_4 = $json_a[$period0]['iconLink'][4];
    $hourly_next_12_iconLink_5 = $json_a[$period0]['iconLink'][5];
    $hourly_next_12_iconLink_6 = $json_a[$period0]['iconLink'][6];
    $hourly_next_12_iconLink_7 = $json_a[$period0]['iconLink'][7];
    $hourly_next_12_iconLink_8 = $json_a[$period0]['iconLink'][8];
    $hourly_next_12_iconLink_9 = $json_a[$period0]['iconLink'][9];
    $hourly_next_12_iconLink_10 = $json_a[$period0]['iconLink'][10];
    $hourly_next_12_iconLink_11 = $json_a[$period0]['iconLink'][11];

    $hourly_next_12_pop_0 = $json_a[$period0]['pop'][0];
    $hourly_next_12_pop_1 = $json_a[$period0]['pop'][1];
    $hourly_next_12_pop_2 = $json_a[$period0]['pop'][2];
    $hourly_next_12_pop_3 = $json_a[$period0]['pop'][3];
    $hourly_next_12_pop_4 = $json_a[$period0]['pop'][4];
    $hourly_next_12_pop_5 = $json_a[$period0]['pop'][5];
    $hourly_next_12_pop_6 = $json_a[$period0]['pop'][6];
    $hourly_next_12_pop_7 = $json_a[$period0]['pop'][7];
    $hourly_next_12_pop_8 = $json_a[$period0]['pop'][8];
    $hourly_next_12_pop_9 = $json_a[$period0]['pop'][9];
    $hourly_next_12_pop_10 = $json_a[$period0]['pop'][10];
    $hourly_next_12_pop_11 = $json_a[$period0]['pop'][11];

    $hourly_next_12_relativeHumidity_0 = $json_a[$period0]['relativeHumidity'][0];
    $hourly_next_12_relativeHumidity_1 = $json_a[$period0]['relativeHumidity'][1];
    $hourly_next_12_relativeHumidity_2 = $json_a[$period0]['relativeHumidity'][2];
    $hourly_next_12_relativeHumidity_3 = $json_a[$period0]['relativeHumidity'][3];
    $hourly_next_12_relativeHumidity_4 = $json_a[$period0]['relativeHumidity'][4];
    $hourly_next_12_relativeHumidity_5 = $json_a[$period0]['relativeHumidity'][5];
    $hourly_next_12_relativeHumidity_6 = $json_a[$period0]['relativeHumidity'][6];
    $hourly_next_12_relativeHumidity_7 = $json_a[$period0]['relativeHumidity'][7];
    $hourly_next_12_relativeHumidity_8 = $json_a[$period0]['relativeHumidity'][8];
    $hourly_next_12_relativeHumidity_9 = $json_a[$period0]['relativeHumidity'][9];
    $hourly_next_12_relativeHumidity_10 = $json_a[$period0]['relativeHumidity'][10];
    $hourly_next_12_relativeHumidity_11 = $json_a[$period0]['relativeHumidity'][11];

    $hourly_next_12_temperature_0 = $json_a[$period0]['temperature'][0];
    $hourly_next_12_temperature_1 = $json_a[$period0]['temperature'][1];
    $hourly_next_12_temperature_2 = $json_a[$period0]['temperature'][2];
    $hourly_next_12_temperature_3 = $json_a[$period0]['temperature'][3];
    $hourly_next_12_temperature_4 = $json_a[$period0]['temperature'][4];
    $hourly_next_12_temperature_5 = $json_a[$period0]['temperature'][5];
    $hourly_next_12_temperature_6 = $json_a[$period0]['temperature'][6];
    $hourly_next_12_temperature_7 = $json_a[$period0]['temperature'][7];
    $hourly_next_12_temperature_8 = $json_a[$period0]['temperature'][8];
    $hourly_next_12_temperature_9 = $json_a[$period0]['temperature'][9];
    $hourly_next_12_temperature_10 = $json_a[$period0]['temperature'][10];
    $hourly_next_12_temperature_11 = $json_a[$period0]['temperature'][11];

    $hourly_next_12_weather_0 = $json_a[$period0]['weather'][0];
    $hourly_next_12_weather_1 = $json_a[$period0]['weather'][1];
    $hourly_next_12_weather_2 = $json_a[$period0]['weather'][2];
    $hourly_next_12_weather_3 = $json_a[$period0]['weather'][3];
    $hourly_next_12_weather_4 = $json_a[$period0]['weather'][4];
    $hourly_next_12_weather_5 = $json_a[$period0]['weather'][5];
    $hourly_next_12_weather_6 = $json_a[$period0]['weather'][6];
    $hourly_next_12_weather_7 = $json_a[$period0]['weather'][7];
    $hourly_next_12_weather_8 = $json_a[$period0]['weather'][8];
    $hourly_next_12_weather_9 = $json_a[$period0]['weather'][9];
    $hourly_next_12_weather_10 = $json_a[$period0]['weather'][10];
    $hourly_next_12_weather_11 = $json_a[$period0]['weather'][11];

// <---------- End Hourly Next 12 ----------> //



?>
```

And you see at the top of the page I REQUIRED the first parse array already parsed into the second parsing page, which now makes it possible to parse the arrays below it, and it works.

Here is the end result PHP Page

```
<?php

require 'req/weatherinfo_hourly.php';

?>

<?php
$bearing = $data_observation_wind_direction;

$cardinalDirections = array(
'N' => array(0, 22.5),
'N' => array(337.5, 360),
'NE' => array(22.5, 67.5),
'E' => array(67.5, 112.5),
'SE' => array(112.5, 157.5),
'S' => array(157.5, 202.5),
'SW' => array(202.5, 247.5),
'W' => array(247.5, 292.5),
'NW' => array(292.5, 337.5)
);

foreach ($cardinalDirections as $dir => $angles) {
 if ($bearing >= $angles[0] && $bearing < $angles[1]) {
 $direction = $dir;
 break;
  }
}
?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PawneeTV Weather - Current Observation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/current_style.css">
</head>

<body>



<?php echo $hourly_next_12_period; ?> | <?php echo $hourly_next_12_time_0; ?                  > 


</body>
</html>
```

And this works!!!!

This is how to get around what I call as a newbie, a Dynamic Array that you need to pre-parse as the array names are constantly changing but you want to keep up with the changes, because if you put a static array name, when the array changes, your code breaks.... this is my way to keep up with it.